# Merge multiple data frames with partially matching rows

Tags: r

I have data frames with lists of elements such as NAMES. There are different names in dataframes, but most of them match together. I'd like to combine all of them in one list in which I'd see whether some names are missing from any of df.

DATA sample for df1:

```
  X                    x
1 1 rh_Structure/Focus_S
2 2 rh_Structure/Focus_C
3 3 lh_Structure/Focus_S
4 4 lh_Structure/Focus_C
5 5   RH_Type-Function-S
6 6        RH_REFERENT-S
```

and for df2

```
  X                    x
1 1 rh_Structure/Focus_S
2 2 rh_Structure/Focus_C
3 3 lh_Structure/Focus_S
4 4 lh_Structure/Focus_C
5 5            UCZESTNIK
6 6                COACH
```

and expected result would be:

```
                  NAME. df1 df2
1                COACH  NA   6
2 lh_Structure/Focus_C   4   4
3 lh_Structure/Focus_S   3   3
4        RH_REFERENT-S   6  NA
5 rh_Structure/Focus_C   2   2
6 rh_Structure/Focus_S   1   1
7   RH_Type-Function-S   5  NA
8            UCZESTNIK  NA   5
```

I can do that with merge.data.frame(df1,df2,by = "x", all=T),
but the I can't do it with more df with similar structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with using `merge` or `*_join`? Is it just that you want to merge more than 2 dataframes? If so, take a look at `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to work with this in a long form. Just `rbind` all the datasets below one another with a flag for which dataset they came from. Then it's relatively straightforward to get a tabulation of all the missing values (and as an added bonus, you can see if you have any duplicates in any of the source datasets):

```
dfs <- c("df1","df2")
dfall <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, mget(dfs), src=dfs))
table(dfall$x, dfall$src)

#                        df1 df2
#   COACH                  0   1
#   lh_Structure/Focus_C   1   1
#   lh_Structure/Focus_S   1   1
#   RH_REFERENT-S          1   0
#   rh_Structure/Focus_C   1   1
#   rh_Structure/Focus_S   1   1
#   RH_Type-Function-S     1   0
#   UCZESTNIK              0   1
```

Comment: Thanks, but honestly, my loops do not work properly, would you write one for me? All files are csv formatted, with the same content, but I cannot collect them as data frames and process them as you suggested. The solution above is fine. I just need to loop it or apply on all csv files to produce one data frame with all data about names in the first column. The data say 1 o 0, so the name exist or not.

Comment: I have, however, all data from those files collected in a list, one after another. I do not know whether that helps.